# No APK file after a succesful build

Tags: android, gradle, javafx, apk, gluon

I made my very first JavaFX application with IntelliJ and I'm trying to build an APK file to "export" in on an Android virtual device.

I'm using gradle and `./gradlew build` is succesful but there is no output directory and no APK file. This is the output of the command:

> Configure project : Project : => no module-info.java found
> BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 906ms 6 actionable tasks: 6 up-to-date

I'm still a beginner at this so I suspect my build.gradle file could be wrong. Here it is :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'https://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.gluonhq:client-gradle-plugin:0.1.36'
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.2"
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.13'
    id 'org.beryx.jlink' version '2.25.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.gluonhq.client-gradle-plugin'

group 'com.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url 'https://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases'
    }
}

ext {
    javafxVersion = '11'
    gluonMobileVersion = '6.0.6'
    gluonAttachVersion = '4.0.12'
    junitVersion = '5.8.2'
}

sourceCompatibility = '11'
targetCompatibility = '11'

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}

application {
    mainModule = 'com.example.cocktailmakergradle'
    mainClass = 'com.example.cocktailmakergradle.CocktailAppRun'
}

javafx {
    version = javafxVersion
    modules = ['javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml', 'javafx.media']
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.openjfx:javafx-controls:${javafxVersion}"
    implementation "org.openjfx:javafx-fxml:${javafxVersion}"
    implementation "org.openjfx:javafx-media:${javafxVersion}"
    implementation "com.gluonhq:charm-glisten:${gluonMobileVersion}"
    implementation "com.gluonhq.attach:util:${gluonAttachVersion}"
    implementation "com.gluonhq.attach:storage:${gluonAttachVersion}"
    // Ajoutez d'autres dépendances Attach si nécessaire
    // Ajout des dépendances Gluon Mobile
    implementation "com.gluonhq.attach:display:${gluonAttachVersion}"
    implementation "com.gluonhq.attach:lifecycle:${gluonAttachVersion}"
    implementation "com.gluonhq.attach:statusbar:${gluonAttachVersion}"
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:${junitVersion}")
    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:${junitVersion}")
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

jlink {
    imageZip = project.file("${buildDir}/distributions/app-${javafx.platform.classifier}.zip")
    options = ['--strip-debug', '--compress', '2', '--no-header-files', '--no-man-pages']
    launcher {
        name = 'app'
    }
}

jlinkZip {
    group = 'distribution'
}

gluonClient {
    target = 'android'
}
```

I tried to us the command line ./gradlew client:built but it's not working and I have this message instead:

> Project 'client' not found in root project.

I also tried ./gradlew assembleDebug but if I have the following error message:

> Task 'assembleDebug' not found in root project.

Comment: That is a very old version of the plugin. You need gluonfx-gradle-plugin version 1.0.18. See https://github.com/gluonhq/gluonfx-gradle-plugin on how to run the different tasks.

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't fix the problem I have.

Comment: Can you update your question with the changes you have done and what tasks are you running now? Also you might want to have a look at https://docs.gluonhq.com/#_the_gluon_plugin_for_intellij_idea